# Obtener datos del Objeto request con metodo PUT?

Tags: php, laravel, postman

tengo un inconveniente con una ruta de laravel que espero alguien me pueda por favor ayudar a resolver.

Tengo definidos ciertos recursos para ser consumidos, a traves de peticiones HTTP.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::apiResources([
        'almacenes' => 'WarehouseController',
        'zonas' => 'ZoneController'
    ]);
});
```

como resultado tengo los sig. recursos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta con la ruta almacenes.update la cual recibe peticiones por medio de los metodos PUT|PATCH, haciendo pruebas con postman efectivamente se puede llegar a la ruta especificada pero el objeto request llega vacío.

```
   /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  integer $warehouse
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $warehouse)
    {
        dd($request->toArray(), $warehouse);
    }
```

De momento el metodo update solo me muestra el objeto request y el parametro de busqueda. Obteniendo el sig. resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando un poco logre conseguir que la petición llegará al metodo correcto con los datos adecuados, agregando el paramtero _method con el valor put en el cuerpo de la petición, pero debo hacer la petición con post en vez de put.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de hacer que la petición llegue completa "con datos" al recurso sin necesidad de cambiar el metodo http ni agregar el parametro _method al cuerpo de la petición?

Comment: Para PUT, PATCH y DELETE, debes agregarle un input como el que muestras, ya que para <html> solo existen GET y POST. O sea, es correcto como lo estás haciendo. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: Pero es que yo no estoy haciendo la petición a travez de un formulario HTML, sino es más como un API REST.

Comment: En Postman tienes marcado 'form-data', o sea que lo envía como datos de un form html. Hay implementaciones para js (axios, ajax, etc), depende de como vayas a usarlo en un caso real

Comment: Comprendo. Muchas gracias @PabloPérezΨ por la explicación era algo que no tenía muy claro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el método de `POST` a `PUT` en Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y envía los datos como json en vez de form-data.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los header asegúrate de agrgar content-type: json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregar que esto funciona también para solicitud que provengan desde `JavaScript`